Missing N in confidence interval for binomial distribution
I am studying on confidence interval for binomial distribution recently. I know general formula for confidence interval is $$ z1⋅\frac{σ}{\sqrt{n}} $$
if I substitute the formula for variance for binomial distribution (1−), I get the following $$ z1⋅\frac{\sqrt{(1−)}}{\sqrt{n}} $$
which is different from the usual binomial distribution confidence interval formula (as shown on Wikipedia under Wald interval) of
$$ z1⋅\frac{\sqrt{(1−)}}{\sqrt{n}} $$
Can I understand why there is a missing n from the second formula above compared to the third?

The general formula that you actually want is $$z \cdot \mathrm{se}(\hat{p})$$
where $\mathrm{se}$ stands for the standard error of your estimator. For your case,
$$\hat{p} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N X_i$$
where $X_i$ are iid Bernouilli trials. Your standard error is then the square root of:
$$Var(\hat{p})= \frac{Var(X_i)}{N}= \frac{p(1-p)}{N}$$
which agrees with your third formula.
